# How do I put a link in option 1, option 2, etc without affecting the layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is being used in Bootstrap 3.0 template.

The code was working fine until I tried putting links into the options part.

The display went back to basic when I tried `<li><a href="">Option 1</a></li>`, help?

HTML code:

```
<a class="btn btn-default btn-select btn-select-light">
    <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
    <span class="btn-select-value">Select Workshop</span>
    <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    <ul>
        <li>Option 1</li>
        <li>Option 2</li>
        <li>Option 3</li>
        <li>Option 4</li>
    </ul>
</a>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-select', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ul = $(this).find("ul");
if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
    if (ul.find("li").is(e.target)) {
        var target = $(e.target);
        target.addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected");
        var value = target.html();
        $(this).find(".btn-select-input").val(value);
        $(this).find(".btn-select-value").html(value);
    }
    ul.hide();
    $(this).removeClass("active");
}
else {
    $('.btn-select').not(this).each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
    });
    ul.slideDown(300);
    $(this).addClass("active");
}
```

});

```
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
var target = $(e.target).closest(".btn-select");
if (!target.length) {
    $(".btn-select").removeClass("active").find("ul").hide();
}
```

});

Comment: did you remove the class on `li`?

Comment: The problem is because the entire code block is already wrapped in an `<a>` element, so you cannot place another one within that. Your generated HTML is invalid and you need to restructure it, or rethink what you're trying to do

Comment: Agree with @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Nested links are illegal**

Links and anchors defined by the `<a>` element must not be nested; an anchor element must not contain any other anchor elements.

When you add a link inside the option, you are trying to do the same. Which isn't the correct approach

Use it as

```
<div class="btn btn-default btn-select btn-select-light">
    <input type="hidden" class="btn-select-input" id="" name="" value="" />
    <span class="btn-select-value">Select Workshop</span>
    <span class="btn-select-arrow glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Option 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Genius. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.